# Rails find record with all association ids matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, associations

I have a HABTM association between Users and Chats. I'm trying to find the Chat with 2 specific users in it. I tried:

```
scope :of_users, ->(user1,user2) { joins(:users).where( users: { id: [ user1.id, user2.id ] } ) }
Chat.of_users( user1, user2 )
```

But it gives me all Chats where one of the two Users is in.

I also tried:

```
Chat.joins(:users) & User.where(id:1) & User.where(id:2)
```

Didn't give me the right results either. What am I looking for? I've been searching all over the place, but I don't know the name of this concept...

**EDIT:**

My Chat model:

```
class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  scope :of_users, ->(user1,user2) { joins(:users).where( users: { id: [ user1.id, user2.id ] } ) }
end
```

My User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :chats
end
```

Schema for User and Chat:

```
create_table "chats", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "chats_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.integer "chat_id"
  t.integer "user_id"
end

add_index "chats_users", ["chat_id", "user_id"], :name => "index_chats_users_on_chat_id_and_user_id"
add_index "chats_users", ["user_id"], :name => "index_chats_users_on_user_id"
```

Comment: Can you show the schema of `Chat`?

Comment: `user1.chats & user2.chats` as per correct HABTM on you user model

Comment: @RajarshiDas Can you provide a code example? I see you're getting chats for both users, but how to get the model that exists in both arrays via a scope or something?

Comment: @RajarshiDas Got it to work! Thanks! Can you put it in an answer so I can give you credit? Or shall I provide the answer myself?

Comment: @Tim done.....put it in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user1.chats & user2.chats` as per correct HABTM on you user model

Answer (score 1):

Use `having` clause to check presence of both users in the associated users

```
scope :of_users, ->(user1,user2) { joins(:users).group("chats.id")
         # the condition within SUM returns 1 if both users present else 0
        .having("SUM(users.id = #{user1.id} AND users.id = #{user2.id}) > 0 ") }
```

Comment: Is this better (ie performance) than `user1.chats & user2.chats` ?

Comment: `user1.chats & user2.chats` makes two sql queries while the scope I suggest makes one sql query with an inner join. For large tables former is better as joining tables can take time. However the `scope` allows you to chain with other scopes and conditions ,  so it is more general. Depends on your use case which one is better suited.