# Find record through association using associations foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, arel

I have the following 4 Models

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :conversation_memberships
   has_many :conversations, :through => :conversation_memberships  
   has_many :messages, :through => :conversations
 end

 class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :messages
   has_many :members, :class_name => 'ConversationMembership', :foreign_key => :conversation_id
   has_many :users, :through => :members
 end

 class ConversationMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :conversation
 end

 class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :conversation
   belongs_to :user
 end
```

So `Conversation` can have many `users` through `ConversationMembership`. Ideally each conversations' set of users is unique, so users `1,2,3` can only have one conversation between them.

With this set up, I'm able to query a `Conversation` for its members id's using the following Rails method:

```
Conversation.find(1).user_ids # => [1,2,3]
```

This gives me the user's ids in the conversation between users `1`, `2` and `3`.

What I'm looking to do is the essentially the **opposite** of this, so try to FIND a conversation between the 3 users and **only** those users. In pseudo code form, something like `Conversation.find_by(:user_ids => [1,2,3])`.

This syntax has the desired effect, but uses 3(or more) queries:

```
User.find(1).conversations & User.find(2).conversations & User.find(3).conversations
```

I was hoping to achieve this with a single query(potentially using sub queries), but for the life of me cannot figure out how to get this working. Its been almost 6 years since I last had to write complex raw SQL like this, so my brain is filled with cobwebs.

**To Summarize:**
I want the ability to query the `Conversation` model and return an existing conversation between 2 or more users.

If all else fails, the closest work around I've been able to come up with is to store the contents of `conversation.user_ids` in an `Array` column on the `Conversation` model.

Comment: The only other relevant post I've found relating to this is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889824/rails-find-record-with-all-association-ids-matching

But it doesn't **really** solve my issue, as it suggests the same `merge` shorthand with `&`, which cannot be chained to `n` number of members without some meta programming

Answer (score 2):

You need to join against the users table:

```
Conversation.joins(:users).where('users.id' => [1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: You can reference the association name in the where call as well:  `Conversation.joins(:users).where(users: { id: [1, 2, 3] })`

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried this before. The issue with this approach comes from multiple associations. So lets say `c = Convo.find(1) && c.user_ids == [1,2]` and `c1 = Convo.find(2) && c1.user_ids == [1,3]` and `c2 = Convo.find(3) && c2.user_ids == [1,2,3]`. Using `Conversation.joins(:users).where('users.id' => [1,2,3])`(or @NathanWallace approach) would return `c`, `c1` **and** `c2` where I only want `c2`

Comment: Let me know if I can format the above a bit better, also thank you both for your responses. If you have any tips to help me format my initial question better so the above comment is clear, let me know

Answer (score 0):

The same problem nearly made me launch my laptop through the window on many occasions, but the following seems to work. If anyone knows a simpler method please speak up.

**Conversation.rb**

```
def self.findConvo(idArr)  # pass in array of user ids
  length = idArr.length
  idString = "('" + idArr.join("','") + "')"  # you have to remove the square brackets and use round ones to keep the sql happy
  @conversation = Conversation.find_by_sql("

      SELECT *
      FROM (
          SELECT cm3.conversation_id
          FROM (
              SELECT       cm1.conversation_id
              FROM         conversationmembership cm1
              WHERE        cm1.user_id IN #{idString}   /* find all conversations involving at least one of our users */
              GROUP BY     cm1.conversation_id
              HAVING       COUNT(cm1.user_id) = #{length}  /* pick out the conversations involving all our users and possibly other users */
          ) AS cm2
          INNER JOIN   conversationmembership cm3
          ON           cm2.conversation_id = cm3.conversation_id   /* get ALL users for our conversations */
          GROUP BY     cm2.conversation_id, cm3.conversation_id
          HAVING       COUNT(cm3.user_id) = #{length}   /* pick out the only conversation involving ONLY our users */
      ) AS cm4
      INNER JOIN   conversations con1
      ON           cm4.conversation_id = con1.id      /* bolt on conversations */

  ")
  return @conversation.first # because @conversation is a collection
end
```